# Magento 2 : Illegal characters on import

Tags: magento2, import, special-character

I'm try to import my customers from magento1 to magento2 but got a few errors on import validation.

The **import** is aimed at a **german shop** so special chars like **"ä, ö, ü"** are pretty common, especially in names and addresses.

I have to change the charset but can't find any spot to do that. So here's the question:

**• Where do I change the charset to make the import possible ?**

**• What do I wrong if it isn't the charset ?**

Charset is: `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: If your tables have `utf8_general_ci` set as default charset, all should be OK. Make sure your import scripts have the correct charset too.

Comment: blame me... got the wrong charset on the csv. Thanks man.

Comment: These things happen haha. I suggest you answer your own question and accept it, or if you think you question wasn't really due to a bug in the first place, close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

The default charset of my CSV editor wasn't UTF-8.

Thats why the import was invalid. Once i changed the csv charset in my editor to UTF-8 the import was valid.

So, the issue is

**Wrong charset on my .csv file**

Comment: You can explain more details?

Comment: The default charset of my csv editor wasnt UTF-8 - Thats why the import was invalid. Once i changed the csv charset in my editor to UTF-8 the import was valid

Comment: btw when exporting, UTF-8 BOM is the encoding used (Idk if this affects smth, thought I should mention it)

Comment: But! if you can't change file encoding? In my case i get data from the file that located on another server by FTP. In this case nee to encode "Name" "on fly".

Answer (score 2):

We can use this website to encode your special characters: http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder

After getting the encoded chars, we need to use the string replace tool to replace the special characters.